Error while loading nlmixr2 R package: error: '.lbfgsb3cPtr' is not an exported object from 'namespace:lbfgsb3c'
I tried to load the new version of nlmixr2 and got the following error
> library(nlmixr2)
Loading required package: nlmixr2data
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘nlmixr2’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'nlmixr2est', details:
  call: NULL
  error: '.lbfgsb3cPtr' is not an exported object from 'namespace:lbfgsb3c'

I tried to remove all the dependencies as well as rxode2 and all its dependencies without success.
> R.version
               _                                
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          3.2                              
year           2023                             
month          10                               
day            31                               
svn rev        85441                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)
nickname       Eye Holes                        
> packageDescription("nlmixr2")$Version
[1] "3.0.0" 


Update all installed packages. Preferably, update R first.
